Is the linear span of characters of $\mathbb{R}$ weak-star dense in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?
For every $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$, define $\phi_a\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ by $\phi_a(x) = \exp(i a x)$.
Is the linear span of $\{\phi_a\colon\ a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ weak-star dense in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?
Is there a simple proof?
I have found the concept of "spectral synthesis" in some books on harmonic analysis, but I haven't found an explicit answer to my question.
Theorem 4.1.1 from Larsen "An Introduction to the Theory of Multipliers" seems to be close to the topic, but it is written in another language.

What does weak-* mean in the context of $L^\infty$?

If you are thinking of $L^{\infty}$ as the dual of $L^{1}$ then  the answer is YES, simply because the only $L^{1}$ function whose FT is $0$ is $0$.

@geetha290krm The predual of $L^\infty$ is unique, up to isometric isomorphism, so that is the only possible way to interpret weak$^\ast$ topology in this context.

@DavidGao Thanks for the comment. I was not aware of this fact.

An interesting thing: the linear span of ${e^{inx}, e^{ix/n}, n\in\mathbb Z}$ is also $w-*$ dense in $L^\infty$, though this is much more difficult to prove

Thanks for the comments. It is so interesting the last fact. Is there any bibliography or references where I could find those results or at least a clue? I mean maybe we can use for example the general theory for locally compact abelian groups but I'd like to find that fact only for the group $(\mathbb{R},+)$.
